# Dynamic WHERE clause IN LOOP AT statement

Tags: loops, dynamic, where-clause, abap

I have to do a loop on my internal table according to a where condition but according to the mode of my program the field of a where condition has to be modified at runtime.

I know that in a SELECT statement it is possible but when I do that in a loop I have an error.

This is my code:

```
CASE gv_cdvue.
  WHEN 'L'.
    lv_condi = 'dcmdr GE gv_daybf   OR dcmdr LE gv_daybf   '.
  WHEN 'C'.
    lv_condi = 'dcldr GE gv_daybf   OR dcldr LE gv_daybf   '.
  WHEN 'E'.
  WHEN OTHERS.


ENDCASE.


  LOOP AT gt_plcad INTO ls_plcad  WHERE (lv_condi).
    ....
  ENDLOOP.
```

My error is :

```
Statement concluding with "...(LV_CONDI)" ended unexpectedly.
```

Comment: IIRC dynamic LOOP...WHERE statements are a rather new addition to ABAP and only possible in NetWeaver 7.31+. What release are you on?

Comment: According to [this](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abaploop_at_itab_cond.htm) it should be possible. What kind of error do you exactly have? Is it a compilation error or a runtime error. Could you post the details of it?

Comment: I wrote inside my error @Jagger, Philip how can i know my relase?

Comment: @shmoolki Please do as written [here](http://scn.sap.com/thread/558734) to check your version of the system.

Comment: I have : Noyau SAP :  720_REL

Comment: @shmoolki Could you post the whole working code? I think the problem is caused by something else but without the whole picture I could not tell.

Comment: @shmoolki Do you get that error when you activate the program or at runtime?

Comment: @shmoolki I tried to reproduce the problem on our system (731) and it worked. By the way, whatever you try is not going to work anyway, because both of your possible conditions will be always true.

Comment: @philip i have Error when i activate. I don't know why?

Comment: @shmoolki What error???

Comment: Statement concluding with "...(LV_CONDI)" ended unexpectedly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting error because of incompatibility of your SAP. Dynamic where condition in the loop is add 7.0 EhP2 version. You should higher than 7.0 Ehp2 then only you can write dynamic where condition.

I Hope this answer will helpful to you.